# Menu overlap and scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sure this is a basic issue. I need some help trying to get a menu to stick to the right side of the screen while the slider moves from one to another as in my example. Also, need to resolve the overflow issue. Can somebody help?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.0.1/css/swiper.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.0.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script> 

    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .swiper-container, .swiper-slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
   .swiper-slide {
   text-align: center;
   background: #fff; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   /* padding: 30px; */
   z-index: 90;
   }
   </style>

   <title></title>


   <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var swiper = new Swiper(...);

   $('.slide-to-link').on('click', function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      swiper.slideTo($(this).attr('data-slide'));
   });
   });
   </script>

   </head>

   <body>


  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#" data-slide="0" class="slide-to-link">Link One</a>
        <a href="#" data-slide="1" class="slide-to-link">Link Two</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>



    <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide One</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide Two</div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
    grabCursor: true
    });
    $('.slide-to-link').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    swiper.slideTo($(this).attr('data-slide'));
    });
    });
    </script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Make a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) so people don't have to copy and paste your code and run it themselves.

Comment: Here you go.
https://jsfiddle.net/dssmnqj3/

Comment: Or full page here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/dssmnqj3/show/light/

Comment: Hew... Can't see no bug here (Chrome on windows, 1600px x 1200px) on any of your 2 Fiddles. Maybe browser related ??

Comment: If I use a background image on the slider, the menu does not sit on the top of the slide, but pushes the slide down the depth of the menu, then the slide doesn't fit the screen.. I.e. I have scroll bars on the left of the browser.

Comment: I've updated jsfiddle.. the links don't sit over the background image.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dssmnqj3/6/